# 'useNaviagte' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've changed useHistory to useNavigate, along with its corresponding syntax in my code, though it still displays as not being defined - 'useNavigate'. Where would I need to define 'useNavigate', as I thought navigate("/search") would be calling useNavigate

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../components/Search.css";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import MicIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mic";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useNaviagte } from "react-router-dom";

function Search({ hideButtons = false }) {
   const [input, setInput] = useState("");
   const navigate = useNavigate();

   const search = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();  


   console.log("You hit the search button >> ", input)

   navigate("/search")
};


   return (
      <form className="search">
          <div className="search__input">
              <SearchIcon className="search__input--icon" />
              <input value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
              <MicIcon />
          </div>

      {!hideButtons ? (
          <div className="search__buttons search__buttons--hiddens">
              <Button type="submit" onClick={search} variant="outlined">
              Google Search</Button>
            <Button variant="outlined">I'm Feeling Lucky</Button>
          </div>
      ): (
          <div className="search__buttons search__buttons--hiddens">
              <Button type="submit" onClick={search} variant="outlined">
              Google Search</Button>
              <Button variant="outlined">I'm Feeling Lucky</Button>
          </div>
      )}
      </form>
);
}

export default Search
```

Comment: you misspelled `useNavigate`  `import { useNaviagte } from "react-router-dom";`

Comment: Typo, you misspelled import. `useNaviagte` vs `useNavigate`. Voted to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".